# UDP обмен сообщениями

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!

Суть проблемы такая: от клиента на сервер отправляется пакет по UDP:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
memoryStream.WriteByte(3);//опкод
/* кодировка сообщения */
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Message);
memoryStream.WriteByte((byte)bytes.Count());//длина сообщения
memoryStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Count());
client.Send(memoryStream.ToArray(), memoryStream.ToArray().Length, "127.0.0.1", 40000);//куда отправлять TODO: ПЕРЕДЕЛАТЬ
```

Как лучше разобрать сообщение на стороне сервера?
Планировал сделать циклом, но не получается
А статично тоже не пропишешь - длина сообщения может отличаться.

На данный момент разбираю так:

```
String message = buffer[2].ToString() + buffer[3].ToString() + buffer[4].ToString() + buffer[5].ToString();
```

Естественно, пример выше - явно не выход

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, но хоть чем-то возможно помогу.

Вы ложите длину в один байт, это 0-255
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5bdb6693(v=vs.120).aspx

Если это ожидаемо, то хорошо.

Дальше как я понимаю вы пишите в поток сообщение, значит с memoryStream[2] начинается сообщение.
То есть Вам нужно взять memoryStream[1] длинну сообщения, и прочесть от memoryStream[2] до указанного значения.

Данный код работает:

```
            //create msg
            byte[] buff;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                memoryStream.WriteByte(3); //опкод
                /* кодировка сообщения */
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test");
                memoryStream.WriteByte((byte)bytes.Count()); //длина сообщения
                memoryStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Count());
                buff = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            //read msg
            var messageLen = buff[1]; //берем длинну сообщения
            //начинаем читать с 3 байта, на указанную длинну
            var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buff, 2, messageLen);
            //выводим результат
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно вычитывать из массива или из стрима куски данных фиксированной длины - то проще использовать [BinaryReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hds7ysb(v=vs.110).aspx) вместо ручного отслеживания смещения:

```
string Message = "test";

MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
memoryStream.WriteByte(3);//опкод
                            /* кодировка сообщения */
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Message);
memoryStream.WriteByte((byte)bytes.Count());//длина сообщения
memoryStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Count());

// на сервере
byte[] buffer = memoryStream.GetBuffer(); // .Receive
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(buffer));
byte opcode = reader.ReadByte(); // 3
byte messageSize = reader.ReadByte(); // 4
string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(reader.ReadBytes(messageSize)); // test
```

Comment: Я бы только не заморачивался с `MemoryStream`'ом, а прямо писал в `NetworkStream` (или куда там надо).

Comment: @VladD я бы тоже (тем более что reader.ReadBytes умеет дожидаться прихода фрагментов, а не тупо падает). Но это вопрос про UDP, а стандартный UdpClient в .net внезапно не поддерживает стримы. Его метод Receive возвращает byte[]. Так что MemoryStream будет нелишним (